# Run same tests on different machines using Run Functional Tests Task TFS 2017

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am able to deploy TestAgent on different machines (Test Agent Deployment task) but when Coded UI tests (Run Functional Tests task) run, only one machine is targeted. I have done the test with only 2 tests. From what I understand, the tests are distributed between machines (with a minimum of 10 tests). But I don't want them to be distributed, I want all the same tests to be executed on all environment I have targeted (Hardware and OS are different between them).

Is there a way to accomplish this in TFS 2017 and still keeping the test report? I could probably run via a script the test on each machines but I would like to keep the reporting.

Thanks.

PS: This is for a proof of concept.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by MrHinsh's answer? Any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you would need multiple Functional Test  tasks that each target a different machene group.

The purpose of running across multiple machenes in a group is merely to expedite testing with parallel execution. The expectation is that all of the machenes in the same machenes group are similar.

You can add separate Functional Test tasks and configure each one, but that will run in serial. If you want to run in parallel then your best option would be to add multiple environments/stages to your release each targeting a separate configuration. Then use the fan-out feature to have each of the 5 configurations run on separate agents in parallel.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was in holiday. I will go by adding multiple environments. I am not familiar with release definition since we do not use it. I will check but this seems to meet my goals. Thanks.